# I am looking at how to convert the following file .gp to csv format while converting coordinates to the velocity and time in R

Tags: r, gps

Looking to convert a .gp file to .csv. This data is an extract from the gps device continuously tracking its position over time.

Further, I would like to find time and velocity throughout.

Here is an example of the output.

```
$GNRMC,020555.90,A,4828.05510,N,12318.87567,W,0.059,,170322,,,A*7E
$GNRMC,020556.00,A,4828.05509,N,12318.87569,W,0.030,,170322,,,A*7D
$GNRMC,020556.10,A,4828.05509,N,12318.87570,W,0.040,,170322,,,A*73
$GNRMC,020556.20,A,4828.05508,N,12318.87571,W,0.018,,170322,,,A*7D
$GNRMC,020556.30,A,4828.05508,N,12318.87572,W,0.043,,170322,,,A*71
$GNRMC,020556.40,A,4828.05508,N,12318.87573,W,0.058,,170322,,,A*7D
$GNRMC,020556.50,A,4828.05508,N,12318.87573,W,0.017,,170322,,,A*77
$GNRMC,020556.60,A,4828.05509,N,12318.87573,W,0.047,,170322,,,A*70
$GNRMC,020556.70,A,4828.05510,N,12318.87572,W,0.041,,170322,,,A*7E
$GNRMC,020556.80,A,4828.05510,N,12318.87573,W,0.075,,170322,,,A*77
$GNRMC,020556.90,A,4828.05511,N,12318.87572,W,0.066,,170322,,,A*74
```

Comment: This _is_ a csv file. You just have to figure out what the different fields mean. I don't think `.gp` is a standard file format. My guess is that the first field is the device, the second a representation of time, the fourth the latitude, the sixth the longitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dat <- read.csv(text=txt, head=FALSE)
dat
#--------------
       V1      V2 V3       V4 V5       V6 V7    V8 V9    V10 V11 V12  V13
1  $GNRMC 20555.9  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.059 NA 170322  NA  NA A*7E
2  $GNRMC 20556.0  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.030 NA 170322  NA  NA A*7D
3  $GNRMC 20556.1  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.040 NA 170322  NA  NA A*73
4  $GNRMC 20556.2  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.018 NA 170322  NA  NA A*7D
5  $GNRMC 20556.3  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.043 NA 170322  NA  NA A*71
6  $GNRMC 20556.4  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.058 NA 170322  NA  NA A*7D
7  $GNRMC 20556.5  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.017 NA 170322  NA  NA A*77
8  $GNRMC 20556.6  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.047 NA 170322  NA  NA A*70
9  $GNRMC 20556.7  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.041 NA 170322  NA  NA A*7E
10 $GNRMC 20556.8  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.075 NA 170322  NA  NA A*77
11 $GNRMC 20556.9  A 4828.055  N 12318.88  W 0.066 NA 170322  NA  NA A*74
```

I found a description of the file format at https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPRMC.htm

[image]

So time is V2 and the velocity in knots is V8:

```
dat$V8
# [1] 0.059 0.030 0.040 0.018 0.043 0.058 0.017 0.047 0.041 0.075 0.066
```

Adendum: Although I answered the specific questions about time and velocity I remained puzzled about the lat and long encoding. I think that it might be encoded as

Dec Mins    3857.5634N09515.92890W
ddmm.mmmm dddmm.mmmm

So the latitude would be 48 deg, 28.055 minutes North and the longitude 123 degrees 18.88 minutes West so this would have been near Centennial Stadium in Victoria BC, Canada. See: https://www.earthpoint.us/convert.aspx for examples of other lat long format options.

Comment: Spectacular find of the format, IRTFM, nice job. I agree with your interpretation of lat/lon ... I can't say I've ever seen that rendition before, but it makes sense and should be easy enough for the OP to process with the `%/%` and `%%` operators.

Comment: The search strategy for file format was to include "$GNRMC" with gps. Finding the lat-long formats was a bit more work. Not sure I understand the proposal to use modulo operators to parse degree minute encoding, since those are not really single numbers. I would have imagined using `gsub("^(\\d{2}", "\\1 ", lat)` and `gsub("^(\\d{3}", "\\1 ", long)`

Comment: that may work too, assuming either (a) nothing is single-digit degrees, or (b) they 0-pad. Lacking that, since `V4` and `V6` appear to be `numeric`, it should suffice to use `lon = V6 %/% 100 + (V6 %% 100)/60` and similar for `lat`., resulting in decimal-degrees `DD.DDDD` format.

Comment: But if they are string and string-ops are preferred, then I'd likely capitalize on the assumption of always 2-digit whole minutes (plus decimal) and allow degrees to be variable, ala `strcapture("^(.+)(..\\..*)", dat$V6, list(deg=0, min=0))` and then converting to whichever format is preferred for actual calcs.

Comment: Pretty sure they 0 pad.

Comment: I think the presumption of "strings" is perhaps moot, as if you just use `read.*` for that, R should default to numeric, making it less efficient to use regex to parse it, preferring the `%/%`/`%%` operators. Either way, nice find.

Comment: OK. Was assuming you were using base 90 or 180. Just using base 100 to isolate or strip off the leading 2 digits might  succeed if you are far enough away from the equator and Greenwich.

Comment: I think we have different views of the `DDMM.MMM` format ... my presumption is that if we strip the `DD` (or `0D` or `DDD`) off the left, then the `MM.MMM` is just that, decimal minutes. Why would proximity to the equator/meridian have an effect on that?

Comment: I thought the leading 0 is the problem when too close to the Equator or Greenwich, not the minutes calculation. Checking just now, I realized it's not.

Comment: I don't see a problem. If `V4 = c(4828.055, 828.055)`, then the original `V4 %/% 100 + (V4 %% 100)/60` produces what I'm assuming are correct: `[1] 48.467583  8.467583`.

Comment: I now agree. Sorry for the noise. `0857.5634 %/% 100
[1] 8`

Comment: Not a problem! Not noise. Confirming I understood the problem (not that I need to solve it, per se). Perhaps the OP will see these comments and take them as suggestions on how to proceed with using the data for other needs.

Comment: Outstanding Googling skills. I figured out the approximate schema but gave up on finding the exact spec after a few tries, assuming that if I hadn't found it by now it must be a proprietary format that wouldn't be publically available.

Comment: @AllanCameron Looks like there are a variety of possible formats: https://anavs.com/knowledgebase/nmea-format/ determined by the leading $-item

Comment: @IRTFM thank you for this! could tell it was coordinates but would not have clued in that the velocity was reported in knots in this file format. Thank you very much